# Waking up pthread_cond_timedwait() before time expires

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, condition-variable

In my project, I'm trying to synchronize multiple threads using the condition variables. Each thread needs to sleep for a given amount of time for each movement. For example, after **Thread A** changes the data and then **it must sleep for 15 seconds**. I accomplished this timed sleeping with pthread_cond_timedwait() since the behavior of sleep() is unpredicted and not stable.

However, I have to wake up all threads before time expires in some cases. Suppose that Thread A is currently sleeping for 15 seconds and relative time is at second 7. When I use pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() to wakeup Thread A before 15 second expires, it does not reflect. Is there any explanation related to this issue? Can I signal the timed condition variable before its time expires?

Pseudocode is like following:

```
vector<pthread_cond_t> cond_list;

void signal_control_function() {
    // this function keeps track of time and send wake-up signals by looping
    if (time == SIGNAL_TIME) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cond_list.size(); i++) {
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond_list[i]);
        }

    }
}

void* thread_function(void* arg) {
   pthread_cond_t cv;
   cond_list.pus_back(cv);
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // make change
        // set up time variable
        pthread_cond_timedwait(&cv, &mutex, &time)
   }
        
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it C++ code?

Comment: Yes, it is C++. I solved the issue. It was related to the scope of the variable. When a declare each condition variable as global and dynamic before the thread and send it as an argument, the code worked without any issue. However, I still do not understand why it does not work when the condition variables are created locally.